# Ggplot, annotate plot with 3 line label with bold text inside

Tags: r, ggplot2, format

I want to put some centered text organized in 3 lines of which the first is bold.

I tried:

```
ggplot() + annotate('label', label = 'atop(bold("text1"), "text2\ntext3")', y = 10, x = 10, parse = T, alpha = .75)
```

but I get:

[image]

Or else:

```
ggplot() +
    annotate('label', label = 'atop(bold("text1"), atop("text2", "text3"))', y = 10, x = 10, parse = T, alpha = .75)
```

[image]

But I'd prefer all 3 lines to be of equal font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put one more `atop`. essentially, if there is only one item in the 'numerator' and two vertical items in the 'denominator' then the item on top will be bigger than the items on the bottom. You'll need blank text in the numerator's numerator.

```
ggplot() + 
  annotate('label', 
           label = 'atop(atop("", bold("text1")), atop("text2", "text3"))', 
           y = 10, x = 10, parse = T, alpha = .75 )
```

[image: two atops in an atop]